# 'Undefined symbols for architecture i386' in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

[image]

It occurs when i use cocoapods and iPhone 4S,5 simulator. All is well when i use the other simulators. The framework Spring, Alamofire and so on are all in pods. Any solutions?

Comment: This can happen if your framework is not linked properly. go to TargetSettings -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources and make sure all these classes implementation (.m) files are added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After one day searching, 'Had a similar problem today. I was able to resolve the issue by deleting all derived data: Windows -> Projects -> Select your workspace -> click "Delete..." next to "Derived Data" on the right side.' helps me.